# Query database for data specific to authenticated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-rds

I am trying to make an API using AWS api-gateway and lambda.

---

Requirements

1. I am trying to build a dashboard, The dashboard will be for multiple organisations and each organisation will have multiple users who can login and see the respective  dashboard.
   Example we have a dashboard for Intel and its accessible by User1, user2, user3
2. A user must be able to login and access the dashboard for his specific Organization and also do CRUD on his data as well

---

I found out that aws cognito with its user pool can be used for the auth process. After that I intend to use api-gateway with lambda function to query a sql database and populate the frontend. The place where I am stuck at is how do I link the user from cognito to corresponding data in database.

In simple applications we would have a user-table and its a simple query but I would appreciate if someone can suggest a good way to go about implementing this